# Signal with spectrum invariant under translation

Tags: signal-analysis

Is there a signal with a spectrum limited in frequency and invariant by translation: $S(\nu)=S(\nu + \alpha), \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: $s(t) = 0$.

Outside of weird mathematical "signals" such as $s(t) = \lbrace t = 17 \rbrace$, this is the only solution.

Comment: Oh, that signal is funky: It's a zero-energy, divergent instantaneous power signal. Niiiiice. But: aren't we missing $s(t) = \text{const.}$, as more general case? The support in freq-domain is finite (in fact, it's infinitesimal) and it's translation-invariant.

Comment: @MarcusMüller One intersting thing about that signal is that its FT is the same as that of $s(t)=0$... I'm glad that there are mathematicians that take care of all those details and we get to use the FT without worries.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The FT of $s(t)=k$ for $k\neq0$ is $k\delta(f)$, right? I don't think it's translation invariant.

Comment: Well, translate $s(t)$ by a time offset $\tau$: $s(t+\tau) = s(t)$. Or are we referring to signals that are invariant to translation in frequency domain?

Comment: Yeah, in the frequency domain: I think that is what the OP is asking about.